# dataTables bundling issue in ASP.net MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a problem with bundling dataTables library. This is what I've got now:

```
//other bundles (bootstrap etc.)

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/datatables").Include(
           "~/Scripts/jquery.dataTables.js"));

bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
           "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
           "~/Content/site.css",
           "~/Content/DataTables/css/dataTables.bootstrap.css",
           "~/Content/DataTables/css/jquery.dataTables.css"));
```

and in **_Layout.cshtml**:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="~/Content/fontawesome-all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

<head>
...
</head>

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/datatables")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work, table is not modified. Another issue is that when I press F12 to inspect my website I don't see `Scripts/datatables` attached on the end, only this:

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

additionally I can see th error: *Uncaught TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function
at HTMLDocument....*

my JS looks like this:

```
$('document').ready(function () {
    $('#myTable').DataTable({
        "order": [[3, "desc"]]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `/Scripts/jquery.dataTables.js` file does not seem to be loading. That is why you see the error on the console.

Can you try to load the datatable library with `<script src="/Scripts/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>` referance instead of the existing  `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/datatables")`?

Also you seem to be loading jquery library twice!?

Comment: I tried this but in vain. I first load js, then dataTables.js, it doesn't work